# Powerpoint macro for picture resize and save as a wmf

Tags: vba, resize, image, wmf

I need help writing a macro witch will complete the following steps:

1. Insert a file (.wmf) - from specific folder on desktop
2. Re-size - aspect ratio off, 8.5" x 15.5"
3. Save as picture .wmf - same file name as original .wmf
4. Repeat steps for all files in folder.

I do this at work to insert resized images into another program that can't re-size non-proportionally. Can't download any new programs to corporate computer, this is the only option that I have at the moment. Doing this one .wmf at a time is very time consuming.

Please HELP.

Comment: have you tried anything on your own? can you show the code we could help you with? if not please check StackOverflow help for further information...

Comment: @KazJaw - Here is what I have so far
Sub Resize()
    Dim sFilename   As String
    Dim sBaseDir    As String
    Dim sInDir      As String
    Dim sOutDir     As String
    Dim sInFile     As String
    Dim sOutFile    As String
    Dim sInDirList  As String
    Dim iCnt        As Integer
    Dim pptLayout   As CustomLayout
    Dim aInDir()    As String
    Dim i           As Integer

Comment: i = 0
    iCnt = 0
    ReDim aInDir(0 To 0) As String
    sBaseDir = "C:\Users\ii38429\Desktop\PPResize"
    
    sInDirList = Dir(sBaseDir & "\*", vbDirectory)
    'save the input folders into an array
    Do Until sInDirList = ""
        If sInDirList <> "." And sInDirList <> ".." Then
            ReDim Preserve aInDir(0 To UBound(aInDir) + 1) As String
            aInDir(i) = sInDirList
            i = i + 1
        End If
        sInDirList = Dir()
    Loop

Comment: For i = 0 To UBound(aInDir)
        sInDir = sBaseDir & "\" & aInDir(i)
        sOutDir = sBaseDir & "_Out\" & aInDir(i)
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir sOutDir
        On Error GoTo 0
        sFilename = Dir(sInDir & "\*", vbNormal)
        Do Until sFilename = ""
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
            sInFile = sInDir & "\" & sFilename
            sOutFile = sOutDir & "\" & sFilename
            With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
                .SlideOrientation = msoOrientationHorizontal
                .SlideHeight = 612
                .SlideWidth = 1116
            End Wit

Comment: ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(sInFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 1116, 612).Select
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Export FileName:=sOutFile, FilterName:="WMF"
            
            'delete current slide and create another blank one for the next graphics file
            Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Delete
            ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide Index:=1, pCustomLayout:=pptLayout
            
            sFilename = Dir()
        Loop

Comment: Next i
    
    MsgBox ("You Looped Through " & iCnt & " Files")
    
End Sub

Comment: This pops a debug error 52 at "sFilename = Dir(sInDir & "\*", vbNormal)" after the first loop any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There's some code on my PPT FAQ site that'll import a folder full of images, one per slide.
With a few mods, you should be able to get it to import an image, scale it to the size you want, then export it.

Batch Insert a folder full of pictures, one per slide
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00352_Batch_Insert_a_folder_full_of_pictures-_one_per_slide.htm

After the code that imports the picture, size it as need be, then add:

oPic.Export "c:\temp\test.wmf", ppShapeFormatWMF

Substitute the path and filename you want to use for "c:\temp\test.wmf" of course.